# Generic Error GDI+ only on remote location

Tags: asp.net

I'm having an error when trying to convert a PDF page to JPEG (and save that JPEG in a shared folder) with this code:

```
static void SavePdfAsJpeg(string originFilename, string destinyFilename)
{
    PdfViewerControl pdfViewer = new PdfViewerControl();
            
    PdfLoadedDocument loadedDocument = new PdfLoadedDocument(originFilename);

    pdfViewer.Load(loadedDocument);
            
    Bitmap[] image = pdfViewer.ExportAsImage(0, loadedDocument.Pages.Count - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < image.Length; i++)
    {
        image[i].Save(destinyFilename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }
}
```

This code works fine when running on  my local machine (Visual Studio), since it doesn't give any error and the image is properly saved in the shared folder.

However, when running this code in IIS in a remote server (which lies on the same network, so it also has access to the shared folder), I get the `Generic Error in GDI+`.

Since this only fails on the server, I'm assuming there must be a different way. I searched online, and found some alternatives, but I haven't found one that 1) Gives no error, but also 2) Actually saves the image in the shared folder.

Comment: Where is `PdfViewerControl` coming from? Possibly something not installed on the IIS server.

Comment: From the syncfusion library. Although the issue itself is on the line "image[i].Save(...)", so I would assume it would tell me the error is that it couldn't find the PdfViewerControl, but the error is thrown at the image.Save line.

Comment: Does this work?  `using (var img = new Bitmap(1, 1)) {                img.Save(destinyFilename, ImageFormat.Jpeg); }` It should save a 1 pixel file, just to make sure its not a permissions thing.